# How to use sed to replace multiple lines

Tags: sed

What would be the right syntax to perform an inplace update to a file from:

```
"redis"=>array(
    'enabled' => false,
```

to

```
"redis"=>array(
    'enabled' => true,
```

I've tried things like but it's not working

```
sed -i "s/\"redis\"=>array(\n    'enabled' => false/\"redis\"=>array(\n    'enabled' => true/" input.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -i '/"redis"=>array($/{N;s/\('"'"'enabled'"'"' => \)false/\1true/}' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/zJnk60):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='"redis"=>array(
    '"'"'enabled'"'"' => false,'
sed '/"redis"=>array($/{N;s/\('"'"'enabled'"'"' => \)false/\1true/}' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
"redis"=>array(
    'enabled' => true,
```

Here,

- `/"redis"=>array($/` - match a line that ends with `"redis"=>array(` string and
- `{N;s/\('"'"'enabled'"'"' => \)false/\1true/}` - `N` appends a newline char and adds the next line to the pattern space, and `s/\('enabled' => \)false/\1true/` matches and captures into Group 1 `'enabled' =>`  substring and then just matches `false` and the `\1true` replaces the match with the Group 1 value + `true` substring.

Comment: Thank you so much! and thanks for the break down - I really need to get a better primer with sed :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have `gnu sed` then your attempted approach will fine with `-z` option:

```sh
sed -i -Ez "s/(\"redis\"=>array\(\n[[:blank:]]*'enabled' => )false/\1true/" file

cat file

"redis"=>array(
    'enabled' => true,
```

**Explanation:**

- `-z`: separate lines by NUL character
- `-E`:  Enable extended regex mode
- `(\"redis\"=>array\(\n[[:blank:]]*'enabled' => )false`: Match `"redis"=>array(` line followed by line break and `'enabled' =>`  part in capture group #1, followed by `false`.
- `\1true`: puts captured value from group #1 followed by `true`

Answer (score 0):

With `perl`:

```sh
perl -0777 -ne '$#ARGV==1 ? $s=$_ : $#ARGV==0 ? $r=$_ :
                print s/\Q$s/$r/gr' search.txt replace.txt ip.txt
```

- `search.txt` file containing content to be searched
- `replace.txt` file containing content to be used for replacement
- `ip.txt` file on which the substitution has to be performed
- `-0777` slurp entire file contents as a single string, so this solution isn't suitable if input file is too large to fit memory requirements
- `$#ARGV` is used to know which file is being read
- `$s` saves the search text, `$r` saves the replacement text
- `s/\Q$s/$r/gr` here, `\Q` is used to match search text literally
- Use `perl -i -0777 ...` for in-place modification.

See my [blog post](https://learnbyexample.github.io/multiline-search-and-replace/) for more examples and alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/"redis"=>array($/!b;n;/^\s*'\''enabled'\'' => false,/s/false/true/' file
```

Look for a line that ends `"redis"=>array(`, print it and fetch the next line.

If that line contains `'enabled' => false,` replace `false` by `true`.